# R Warning: newdata' had 15 rows but variables found have 22 rows

Tags: r, prediction, non-linear-regression

I have read few answers on this here but I am afraid I have not been able to figure out an answer.

My R code is:

```
colors <- bmw[bmw$Channel=="Colors" & bmw$Hour=20,]
colors_test <- tail(colors, 89)
colors_train <- head(colors, 810)

colors_train_agg <- aggregate(colors_train$Impressions, list(colors_train$`Position of Ad in Break`), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
colnames(colors_train_agg) <- c("ad_position", "avg_impressions")
lm_colors <- lm(colors_train_agg$avg_impressions ~ poly(colors_train_agg$ad_position, 12))
 summary(lm_colors)

colors_test_agg <- aggregate(colors_test$Impressions, list(colors_test$`Position of Ad in Break`), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
colnames(colors_test_agg) <- c("ad_position", "avg_impressions")
new.df <- data.frame(colors_test_agg$ad_position)
colnames(new.df) <- c("ad_position")
colors_test_test <- predict(lm_colors, newdata=new.df)
```

So I have exactly the same column names for both training and test data. I still get the warning:

`Warning message:
'newdata' had 15 rows but variables found have 22 rows`

Can some one suggest what is wrong? Also, I want to know if I am even doing it the right way.

Also, some pointers on how to calculate accuracy of the model will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: prefer `lm(avg_impressions ~ poly(ad_position, 12), data = colors_train_agg)`

Comment: Being as the question is about row inconsistency it would help if you provided a few dimensions. `lapply(list(colors_test, colors_train, colors_train_agg, colors_test_agg), dim)`

Comment: Can you provide the data?

Comment: Using `lm_colors <- lm(avg_impressions ~ poly(ad_position, 13), data=colors_train_agg)` worked. Thanks @joel.wilson.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: though we solved your problem, alwas have an habit of posting a comp[lete question ( includes a sample small data) for us to work on

Comment: Sure @joel.wilson Sorry about the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solution :

```
lm_colors <- lm(avg_impressions ~ poly(ad_position, 13), data=colors_train_agg)
```

Reason :
you can compare yourselves how `model.matrix()` generates the matrix to score the data inside `predict()`. So when we pass `model(df$var1~df$var2)`, `model.matrix()` looks for `df$var1` and `df$var2` to generate the matrix- but this has dimensions of training data (df). Problem of having different names in the `model` and in `newdata`

go through below steps( if you are interested in knowing the cause) :

```
model1 <- lm(var1~var2, data = df)
model2 <- lm(df$var1~df$var2)
debug(predict)
predict(model1, newdata = df1)
predict(model2, newdata = df1)
```